Confusion regarding solar power?
I was reading book of gilbert and i came across the following statement
One of the most useful ways to describe energy production from a PV array
is in terms of kWh/yr delivered per kW of STC rated power
It is also shown highlighted in attached snap
What it means? According to my understanding, it means that if our our solar systems has capacity 1 kw dc then the total energy produced by it in a year time will be in kWh/yr


Engr - Hi, Please add a proper citation in the text, for the source of the copied material, as required by the site rule on referencing. It seems that the source is a book (I'm assuming that the PDF in your screenshot is not public) so the rule says: "For non-web-based citations, include the source to the best of your ability (title, author, page number, etc).". It also helps to include the book edition & publisher. As it says, please cite the source to the best of your ability. TY

Engr - Hi, Please add a comment to confirm that you understand your mistake, with the lack of a proper citation for the copied image in your question. When you have confirmed that you understand the problem, either you can add a proper citation, or we can reapply the helpful edit originally made by Velvet. TY

You are correct.
STC stands for Standard Test Conditions.  PV modules are tested under conditions, which specify temperature, atmosphere (air density), the amount of light falling on the module per unit area, & the spectral make-up of the light.  The latter is sometimes called "Stantard Solar Spectra", and is intended to accurately copy the spectra of normal sunlight.
The rated STC output power is measured right at the terminals of the module, and at the current that gives maximum power - known as the "maximum power point".  A real-world PV module installation will have a different (usually lower) output power, due to power losses caused by cables, module mismatch, dirt on the module, inverter, temperature, and solar radiation.  The latter two items depend strongly on the geographic location.
So yes, given the module STC power rating, this factor allows you to calculate the energy produced per year (in kWhr).  What you will actually get in reality will depend on how closely the assumptions apply to your particular installation.  Issues such as shading, orientation & elevation, local weather, & how often you clean the panels, will all impact how well the modules perform.


One of the most useful ways to describe energy production from a PV array is in terms of kWh/yr delivered per kW of STC rated power.

It's just saying that you can't multiply the STC1 rated power by the number of hours in a year to get the total energy output. The output will depend on the insolation, which in turn depends on latitude, cloud cover, angle of incidence of sunlight (which will vary with time of year), length of day (latitude again), etc. Then there are losses in conversion to AC (hence the reference to DC output). The kWh rating is a useful energy metric for calculation of return on investment, etc.
There are 8,760 hours in a 365 day year. A 1 kW continuous generator would generate 8,760 kWh in that year. Note that the book quotes annual energy delivery of 1000 to 1600 kWh/year for each kW of DC at the panel. This is 11.5% to 18% "effectiveness" if you like.
1 Standard Test Conditions.
